# group by, order by, distinct together

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table with three columns (Trader, Product, Price). I want to get each Trader once and Product with max price to that Trader. When I select following I see repeated Traders:

```
select Trader, Product, Max(Price) as Price
from dbo.Sell
group by Trader, Product 
order by Max(Price) desc
```

How can distinct Trader for the query above? The query below doesn't change anything:

```
select distinct Trader, Product, Max(Price) as Price
from dbo.Sell
group by Trader, Product 
order by Max(Price) desc
```

Actually the following query does almost I want, however I want to see Product instead of Price.

```
select Trader, Max(Price) as Price
from dbo.Sell
group by Trader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, you would get multiple records only if a trader has more than one product with max price.

```
;with cte as (
    select Trader, Max(Price) as Price
    from dbo.Sell
    group by Trader
)
select cte.Trader, s.Product, cte.Price
from cte join dbo.Sell s
         on cte.Trader = s.Trader and cte.Price = s.Price
order by cte.Price desc
```

Second method would be to use a `rank()` function, but again rank() function will bring multiple records for same price records.

**To get a single record**, you can use `Row_Number()` in place of `Rank()`.

```
;with cte as (
    select Trader, Product, Price, 
         Rank() over (partition by Trader order by Price desc) rnk
    from dbo.Sell

)
Select Trader, Product, Price 
From cte
Where rnk = 1
Order by Price desc
```

Comment: No, It doesn't look fine because prices can be the same for several rows.

Comment: If you have `more than one product per trader with more than one max price`, which one do you need to select?

Comment: Where MAX(Price), TOP 1 maybe.

Comment: Well, you can have more than one record with same `MAX(Price)`. You have to select them all or specify a one of which. `TOP 1 decides by the order`, then what is the order in which you need to select the TOP 1?

Comment: I meant if we have the same records we have to show only one, no matter which one, because they are the same. But thanks, actually it works fine to me.